# Passing base address of an array

Tags: arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo( int [] );

int main()
{
    int ary[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(ary);
    printf("%d ", ary[0]);
}

void foo(int p[4])
{
  int i = 10;
  p = &i;
  printf("%d ", p[0]);
}
```

Can anyone please explain me the above code. I am getting output as 10 (in foo) and 1(in main).
But i expect 10 and 10 (in both foo and main). As in the function foo base address is pointing to &i.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is effectively local to `foo` (think of it as a local variable that gets initialized w/ data from the caller), so changes to it are not reflected in the matching argument (in this case, `ary`).  Now, if you changed the *content* of the array (that is, what both `p` and `ary` point *to*), that would be reflected in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer `p` is local to function `foo`. So changing it's value will not affect the array of `main` function.

If you want to change the value of `ary` from function `foo` try this: (of course exclude `p = &i`)

```
p[0] = i;
```

This will make `ary[0] = 10`

Comment: One doubt: As you told p is local to the function, and how does p[0] make changes to arr.  Also what is passed when i sent array as an parameter,

Comment: It is simple, `p` is local to `foo` but it still points to `ary` until it is assigned otherwise.  After  `p = &i` `p` no more points to `ary`. Could I make it clear?

Comment: i have one more questions regarding function pointer, is function pointer resolve at compile time or at runtime? please give me brief on either case

Comment: Every functions other than `virtual function` are resolved in compile time. And if any of the answers solve your question you can accept that.